# CSS Only Tooltip Arrow - With Background, Border & Box-shadow?

Tags: css

### Tooltip CSS

```
.has-tooltip .tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -40px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: ease-out 300ms opacity;
       -moz-transition: ease-out 300ms opacity 0ms;
         -o-transition: ease-out 300ms opacity 0ms;
            transition: ease-out 300ms opacity 0ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0ms;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.has-tooltip .tooltip span {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(45, 45, 45, 1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,0.60);
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
       -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
}
```

### [View Live Example](http://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/jBdvmp?editors=1100)

### What I Am Trying To Achieve

By only having one element, have a tooltip styled as seen in the link above with a tooltip arrow which also has the same look applied to appear to be one element. I've seen multiple which place another element within for the arrow however I'm hoping to achieve this without needing to do so.

### Questions

How can I have a tooltip arrow which gives the impression it is part of the tooltip with the same styles applied.

**Note:** If you provide code, could you please fully explain what you have done so I can implement a top tip as well as a bottom tip.

Comment: So you want whatever background applied to the tooltip, the arrow should have that same background.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element, i.e. `::before`, and by rotate it 45 deg and positioning it about half its height from the bottom so it looks like an arrow.

```css
a.has-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
a.has-tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%; top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,-150%);
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  border: 4px solid #999;
}
a.has-tooltip span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%; top: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: inherit;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index: -1;
  border: inherit;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

a.has-tooltip:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<a href="#" class="has-tooltip" id="link"><span>Hi! I'm a tooltip!</span>
  Hi! I'm a link!
</a>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

When one make a shadow like this, and as it is actually a square, their 2 shadows intersect

```css
a.has-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
a.has-tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%; top: -10%;
  transform: translate(0,-150%);
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
a.has-tooltip span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%; top: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
       box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
}

a.has-tooltip:hover span { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" class="has-tooltip" id="link"><span>Hi! I'm a tooltip!</span>
  Hi! I'm a link!
</a>
```

To fix that is almost impossible, unless one use a SVG, though here is 2 possible solutions.

1. Give the shadow a non transparent color

```css
a.has-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
a.has-tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%; top: -10%;
  transform: translate(0,-150%);
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(128,128,128,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(128,128,128,1);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(128,128,128,1);
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
a.has-tooltip span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%; top: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px 2px rgba(128,128,128,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px 2px rgba(128,128,128,1);
       box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px 2px rgba(128,128,128,1);
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
}

a.has-tooltip:hover span { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" class="has-tooltip" id="link"><span>Hi! I'm a tooltip!</span>
  Hi! I'm a link!
</a>
```

2. Use the other pseudo, `::after`, as the shadow, which will be transparent. With this one need to play a little with the size of the main shadow and the position of the `::after` pseudo.

```css
a.has-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
a.has-tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%; top: -10%;
  transform: translate(0,-150%);
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
a.has-tooltip span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%; top: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
}
a.has-tooltip span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(10% - 5px); top: calc(100% + 6px);
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-top: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  z-index: -2;
}

a.has-tooltip:hover span { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" class="has-tooltip" id="link"><span>Hi! I'm a tooltip!</span>
  Hi! I'm a link!
</a>
```

Comment: I replaced the styles you used with my own however on the tooltip arrow you can see a double box-shadow. Do you have any idea how I could work around this? Take a look at my [demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgc7cju4/1/).

Comment: @TimMarshall Updated with 2 samples, none perfect but as close as I could

Comment: @LGSon on hover, your text appears to move 1-2px down on the tooltip, can't see why this is happening otherwise thank you for the extra help!

Comment: @TimMarshall You're welcome. I tried all mine and no move of any text. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Google Chrome, upon hovering, when the text shows, a second or less later, the text in the tooltip moves down 1-2px

Comment: @TimMarshall Don't know what's going on with your Chrome, mine doesn't do that (ver. 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)) .... also tested with Edge/Firefox, no issues

Comment: Strange, it only happens on SO though! No worries :)

Comment: @LGSon I know you've long answered my original question however I've got a new very similar one along side and was wondering if you could lend another hand? Please see my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/peYozE) where I am trying to add a close for a future implement to have on click sticks it there then you close via the close button.

Comment: Just to note that I know this looks like a large close but the tooltip/popup would be much bigger. I'll also reward you with some more rep!

Comment: @TimMarshall Since you can't upvote more than once I won't answer ... ;) ... just kidding, will have a look later, though I think a SVG will be needed for this one

Comment: Actually @LGSon I placed my first bounty the other day and there was an option to give a chosen answer more rep which I only discovered recently myself!

Comment: @TimMarshall That can't be done properly using plain CSS, you'll need a SVG